# C++ Passing Const Object Reference Into Constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I am currently designing a class that will reference the data of another object. In this new class, I am attempting to pass an object reference such that the new class can view values of the object without having to copy the original data of the object. However, I am struggling with this.

I currently have the following class prototype:

```
Force2Motion(const RigidBody& rigid_body);
```

So when I pass this reference into the constructor, I would like to save this for future use after the object has been initialized. Thus I want some way to say

```
RigidBody _memberObject = rigid_body;
```

However, I want to avoid copying all of rigid_body into its own object. Instead, I was thinking that it would be more appropriate to do something like this

```
// Force2Motion Member Object
RigidBody& _rigidBody;
```

And then during object creation have the following constructor

```
Force2Motion(const RigidBody& rigid_body):
    _rigidBody(rigid_body)
```

However, this throws an error saying that I am not allowed to assign a reference to a const reference. I want to make sure that this new class does not reassign the constructor reference, thus I believe I need the const.

I did realize that if I were to initialize the member object as a const reference it would allow me to run the constructor fine, but then I couldn't use any of the objects member functions because the compiler thought that accessing the member function could possibly change the data of the original object reference.

Such that I have:

```
const RigidBody& _rigidBody;
```

with constructor

```
 Force2Motion(const RigidBody& rigid_body):
      _rigidBody(rigid_body)
```

Are there changes that can be made to the RigidBody class such that I can still use member functions even if I have declared an object as const? As in, can I mark certain functions such that they indicate accessing them will not change any data within the object?

Thanks for any help!

Edit: In my process of describing the problem, I realized the real question in which I should have been asking. Thus I was easily able to search for the question. Check out this [link](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/810-const-class-objects-and-member-functions/). It explains that if you initialize an object as a const, you will not be able to access any member function of that object since accessing member functions can possibly change data within the object that was defined as a const. Thus, if you have a member function that you KNOW will not change the data of the object, you need to mark that function with a const keyword (refer to the link for specifics). Doing so will allow you to declare an object as const yet still have access to certain member functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Member functions can be made const

```
void myFunction() const;
```

Using this `const` makes the `this` pointer const, thus meaning you cannot modify member variables or call other non-const member functions. There are some exceptions to this, like `const_cast` and the `mutable` keyword. But those should probably be avoided.

A good, simple example of when to use this `const` is on getters.

```
int getSize() const
{
   return size;
}
```

Since nothing will change, this function can be called on a const or non-const object.